# Consecutive WITH clauses

Tags: sql, postgresql, with-statement

In Postgres sql, is it possible to have consecutive WITH statements? e.g.

```
WITH t1 AS (
   ...some select statement
)

WITH t2 AS (
   ...select from t1
)

SELECT * FROM t2;
```

I have tried the above and it does;t seem to be working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
WITH t1 AS (
   ...some select statement
),

t2 AS (
   ...select from t1
)

SELECT FROM t2;
```